# How to split a multi-gigabyte file into chunks of about 1.5 gigabytes using Linux split?

Tags: linux, shell, split, logic

I have a file that can be bigger than 4GB. I am using the linux `split` command to split it by lines (that's the requirement).
But after splitting the original file, I want the size of split file to be always less than 2GB. 
The original file size can vary from 3-5 GB. 
I want to write some logic for this in my shell script and feed the number of lines into my `split` command below to keep the split file sizes less than 2 GB.

```
split -l 100000 -d abc.txt abc
```

Comment: How many lines in the typical file?  How much do the line lengths vary?  Can you do some arithmetic, including a margin for error, on how many lines to request? Have you looked at the options on your `split` command?  Does it the support `-C` option?  (GNU `split` says: _`-C`, `--line-bytes=SIZE`
              put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file_ — that sounds like it might be what you want.)

Comment: This is tagged "unix" (GNU split would be appropriate if tagged "linux").  He can certainly do a `wc`, and if clever enough with scripting can adjust that with a binary-search to ensure it fits in 2Gb (seems more than a 15-minute exercise though--past my level of interest).

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler  and Thomas for your feedback. 
This is what i thought of doing.   

1. Do "wc -l abc.txt"  - This will give me total no of lines in that file. 

2. Get the file size of original file abc.txt and divide it by no of lines in that file = Will give me size per line. 

3.Divide 1.5 GB or any number less than 2GB by size per line = Will give me no of lines.

4. Use the no of lines i got from step 3 in my split command. 

Please chip in your feedback. TIA :)

Comment: Roughly, yes.  That's why I asked the questions about the file and line sizes.  You could run into problems if your file has many lines that are 10 bytes long and a few that are 20 KiB long; you might accidentally get a huge block of 20 KiB lines that blows your limit because they are all grouped together.  However, the chances are that your data is uniform enough that you won't run into such problems.  Consider whether it is worth installing GNU `split` on your machine (not in place of the standard issue `split`; install it in a separate directory, such as `/usr/gnu/bin`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No of lines vary from file to file, but one of the file i am working on have 328969322 lines, and file size is 52.5GB. Yes i checked the options of my split, it does support -C option. 
How do i use that in my problem ? Thanks

Comment: `csplit -C 1500000000 datafile`?  Or, if you want 1.5 GiB, then use `csplit -C 1610612736 datafile`.  When I experimented with `csplit -C 20` and some of the lines were 40 bytes long, the long lines were split, but the shorter lines were grouped to make files up to 20 bytes long.  Check it out on small data files (and small sizes of the chunk size).  It appears your lines are about 170 bytes each on average, so you shouldn't have any problems with untoward splits.  If need be: `sed 1000q datafile | split -C 1700 -` should give you about 100 files with about 10 lines in each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how I solved this problem. Sorry for posting the solution late.

**1. Declared a global variable DEFAULT_SPLITFILE_SIZE= 1.5Gb**

```
DEFAULT_SPLITFILE_SIZE=1500000000
```

**2. Calculated no of lines in the file.**

```
LINES_IN_FILE=`wc -l $file | awk '{print $1}'`

echo `date`  "Total word count = ${LINES_IN_FILE}."
```

**3. Calculated the size of a file.**

```
FILE_SIZE=`stat -c %s "${file}"`
```

**4. Calculated size of each line in the file.**

```
SIZE_PER_LINE=$(( FILE_SIZE / LINES_IN_FILE ))

echo `date`  "Bytes Per Line = $SIZE_PER_LINE"
```

**5. Calculated the no of lines needed to make it a 1.5gb split file.**

```
SPLIT_LINE=$(( DEFAULT_SPLITFILE_SIZE / SIZE_PER_LINE ))

echo `date`  "Lines for Split = $SPLIT_LINE"
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

*Seeking clarification:* How many lines in the typical file? How much do the line lengths vary? Can you do some arithmetic, including a margin for error, on how many lines to request? Have you looked at the options on your split command? Does it the support the `-C` option? (GNU `split` says: `-C, --line-bytes=SIZE put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file` — that sounds like it might be what you want.)

> This is what I thought of doing.
>
> 1. Do `wc -l abc.txt` — This will give me total no of lines in that file.
> 2. Get the file size of original file abc.txt and divide it by no of lines in that file; that will give me size per line.
> 3. Divide 1.5 GB or any number less than 2GB by size per line; that will give me no of lines.
> 4. Use the no of lines I got from step 3 in my split command.

That's why I asked the questions about the file and line sizes. You could run into problems if your file has many lines that are 10 bytes long and a few that are 20 KiB long; you might accidentally get a huge block of 20 KiB lines that blows your limit because they are all grouped together. However, the chances are that your data is uniform enough that you won't run into such problems.

Consider whether it is worth installing GNU split on your machine (not in place of the standard issue `split`; install it in a separate directory, such as `/usr/gnu/bin`).

> The number of lines varies from file to file, but one of the files I am working on has 328969322 lines, and the file size is 52.5GB. Yes, I checked the options of my `split` and it *does* support `-C` option. How do I use that in my problem?

I note that this data file is considerably bigger (about ten times bigger) than the sizes mentioned in the question.  However, that's not a major problem.

```
csplit -C 1500000000 datafile
```

Or, if you want 1.5 GiB rather than 1.5 GB, then use:

```
csplit -C 1610612736 datafile
```

When I experimented with `csplit -C 20` and some of the lines were 40 bytes long, the long lines were split (maximum length 20 bytes), but the shorter lines were grouped to make files up to 20 bytes long. Check out your code on small data files (and small sizes of the chunk size).

From the data you give, it appears your lines are about 170 bytes each on average, so you shouldn't have any problems with untoward splits. If need be, you can experiment with something like:

```
sed 100q datafile | split -C 1700 -
```

That should give you about 10 files with about 10 lines in each.

Comment: sed 100q datafile | split -C 1700 -
This gave me 100 files and not 10 files. Also in above line did you meant 170 or 1700 , as 170bytes is the avg per line.

And -C option is not supported when i tried to use csplit as you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: The intention was to get 100 lines, each of about 170 bytes, and split them into 10 files of up to 1700 bytes each.  If any line is longer than 1700 bytes, then that line will be split.  Otherwise, this will avoid splitting lines. If you got 100 files, then either I miscalculated the bytes per line of your initial rows in the file are long (sufficiently long that two lines don't fit into 1700 bytes, so over 850 bytes each, roughly speaking).  You said 328969322 lines and 52.5 GB; that amounts to about 171 bytes per line; I used 170 as the third significant digit is probably spurious accuracy.

Comment: Also, `csplit` is a context-split command and I never suggested using it.  You told me that `split -C` was supported on your machine.  If it isn't, then either you need to get GNU `split` (which does support it; it is a part of the GNU CoreUtils package) and install it, or you have to go back to your calculations.  If 1.7 GB files are OK, then use `split -l 100000` to break the file into 100,000 line chunks.  If that's too big, scale the number to 88000 or maybe 85000.  What you choose depends on the consequences of choosing a file size that's too big or too small.

Comment: If that doesn't work sanely, your input lines are very non-uniform.  Maybe you need to generate a histogram of the line lengths so you can work out what might be acceptable.  Maybe you need to randomize the file before processing it further.  I do think this is all stuff I covered in my first comment (albeit very tersely) nearly 4 days ago.  You have to know what your tools can do, and you have to know the shape (and size) of your data files.

Answer (score 0):

It's always advisable to refer the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split) before posting the question. Split command provides an option to split the files on bytes. Below is the option which you can find in the manual page of split command.

> ```
>    -b, --bytes=SIZE
>           put SIZE bytes per output file
> ```

```
split --bytes=1500000000 abc.txt abc
```

You need not explicitly specify the number of lines. This command serves your purpose.

Comment: Thanks Venkat, but if you read my question again. I said requirement is to split the file by no of lines, in the process also make sure that after splitting the file sizes is less than 2GB. 
Off course i know i can do it by giving the byte size. I have done my research before posting the question.

Comment: Note that `split -b` breaks at a byte count, part way through a line if need be.  That is not what is wanted.